# Use the sampleTime operator without a prefixed delay?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have an observable stream that emits a sequence of numbers. Each emitted value requires a heavy UI update to reposition components.

So I've been using the `sampleTime()` operator to throttle the emitted values into periodic intervals, and this works perfectly.

For example;

```
observable.pipe(sampleTime(250)).subscribe(value => console.log(value));

// outputs (periods are delays)
...10...11...12......................14...15...16
```

This works great at throttling the updates of the UI into slower intervals of updates.

I've run into the problem that `sampleTime(250)` will prefix all emitted values with a 250ms delay. So in the above example, the value **14** is not emitted until 250ms later. The problem is that there was a **long delay** before the value 14.

So I need an observable stream that throttles values by 250ms using sampleTime(), but I want no initial delay 250ms for the first value after an idle period.

For example;

```
// currently 
...10...11...12......................14...15...16
^^^ remove these dots             ^^^ remove these dots

// what I really want
10...11...12...................14...15...16
```

I can't think of a better way to explain it.

Comment: I think you need [throttleTime](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttleTime) instead

Comment: @Andrey so many operators and so little time. I think that would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Not sure if `throttleTime` is what you really want because it'll ignore subsequent emissions. Maybe this would work `throttleTime(250, undefined, { leading: true, trailing: true })`

Comment: @martin yeah, I tried just throttleTime() and the layout was wrong because it was missing the last emitted value. I'll try those params.

Comment: Isn't sampleTime also ignoring some events? EDIT: Ah got it, throttle will ignore last emit, then indeed `{trailing: true}` is what needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe for your usecase [throttleTime](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttleTime) is more suitable. Let's see the difference using documentation pictures:

As you can see throttleTime has no padding at the beginning

sampleTime: [image: Sample time timeline]
throttleTime: [image: Throttle time timeline]

Comment: Thanks, this works and if I enable leading/trailing values it does EXACTLY what I want. Rxjs is really amazing.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't swap sampleTime for throttleTime in this case. They're totally different. throttleTime seems to be a replacement for what you want to achieve but it's doesn't do exactly what you expect.